# Custom shortcode with do_shortcode and substr

Tags: functions, shortcode

I'm creating my own shortcode, and within that function I'm calling a different shortcode through do_shortcode. I'm trying to call a substr after the do_shortcode call, but I'm not getting expected results. It seems like substr is being called before do_shortcode can resolve. Example:

```
function my_shortcode_function() {
    $string = "";
    $string = do_shortcode('[different_shortcode]');
    $string = substr($string, 4);
    return $string;
}
add_shortcode( 'my_shortcode', 'my_shortcode_function' );
```

This is returning "ferent_shortcode]" and not returning a string that should be resolved through the do_shortcode.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: please post the code of the 'different_shortcode' function; does that also happen if the '[different_shortcode]' is a generic shortcode like '[caption]'

Comment: I created a different simple shortcode that returns the post permalink, and that does work correctly. Unfortunately, the shortcode I'm calling is in a different plugin, and I'm not sure how to fix this issue. It's called Store Locator Plus, and they have a bunch of shortcodes documented here: https://www.storelocatorplus.com/documentation/store-locator-plus/user-experience/results/results-layout/

Comment: try to contact the developer of the plugin for help - not everything in square brackets is shortcode as defined in the WordPress shortcode API ...

Answer (score 0):

using php substr requires you add a start point when calling substr function
http://php.net/manual/en/function.substr.php

A possible fix:

```
function my_shortcode_function() {
$string = "";
$string = do_shortcode('[different_shortcode]');
$string = substr($string, 0, 4);
return $string;
}

add_shortcode( 'my_shortcode', 'my_shortcode_function' );
```

Comment: Sorry, but that didn't work.